# When using the Tcl/Tk C API on MacOSX why does it execute in an environment?

Tags: c, macos, tcl, tk-toolkit

I've created a program linking against the [Tcl/Tk](http://www.tcl.tk/) libraries on MacOS 10.8.5 to create a cross-platform GUI. At the most basic level i created a Tcl/Tk interpreter using [Tcl_CreateInterp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/CrtInterp.htm) in my program and i can successfully issue [Tk commands](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/contents.htm) to it to create the GUI.

On Linux everything works as expected and behaves as a native GUI application but on MacOS the program seems to run inside some kind of environment.

Below you can see the splash screen presented after selecting the `About` menu item and judging by the file menu this environment can execute other scripts via the `Source...` menu item. You can even run a widget demo here too!

Any idea what's going on here or how i can make this program behave as if it's a normal GUI application without this environment? Are there Tcl/Tk calls i'm missing?

[image: splash screen]
[image: menu]

Comment: It's just some default handlers IIRC

Comment: So you mean if I add a menu etc it will replace these defaults? My little framework isn't that feature rich yet but I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research i can safely say it's a default menu bar provided by MacOS. If you create another menu and assign it to the top level window, it replaces this default one.

It's also mentioned here: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html

> Because on Mac OS X all windows have a menubar, it's important to make
>   sure you do define one, either for each window or a fallback menubar
>   for the root window. Otherwise, you'll end up with the "built-in"
>   menubar, which contains menus that are only intended for use when
>   typing commands directly into the interpreter.